# Nested form_for in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-form-for

I have `Test` model and `User` model. `Test` model is having many `users`. Test controller is as below.

```
class TestController
   def create
      Test.create(testparams)
   end

   private
   def testparams
      params.require(:test).permit(:test_name,user_attributes:[:user_name])
   end
end
```

In the above code new Test would be created. I want to create new users for a existing test.How to do that??

Comment: If you google rails nested forms, you will find a multitude of resources to get you started. Maybe start with the rails guide, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms.

Comment: My question is about nested form_for of existing object(in this case test object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to apply the same principles. Below is a basic framework which you will have to alter depending on your requirements.

test model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true
```

tests_controller

```
def edit
  @test = Test.find(params["id"]
  @test.users.build
end

def update
  @test = Test.find(params["id"]
  @test.update(testparams)
end
```

test view

```
<%= form_for @test do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :test_name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :users do |uf| %>
    <%= uf.text_field :user_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```